# Polymorphic components for graphics and program state

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, monads, state

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333788/how-to-create-an-interface-for-a-stateful-component-where-the-state-type-is-opaq) on StackOverflow, got some answers, most notably a link to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915923/combining-multiple-states-in-statet), and basing on that I've implemented this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

-- Module
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
newtype Module m a b =
    Module (a -> m (b, Module m a b))

{-
instance (Monad m) => Applicative (Module m a)
instance (Monad m) => Arrow (Module m)
instance (Monad m) => Category (Module m)
instance (Monad m) => Functor (Module m a)
-}

-- GraphicsModule
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data GraphicsState = GraphicsState Int

render :: (MonadState GraphicsState m, MonadIO m) => Int -> m ()
render x = do
    (GraphicsState s) <- get
    liftIO $ print $ x + s
    put . GraphicsState $ s + 1

type GraphicsModule = Module IO Int ()

initialGraphicsState = GraphicsState 0

createGraphicsModule :: GraphicsState -> GraphicsModule 
createGraphicsModule initialState = Module $ \x -> do
    (r, s') <- runStateT (render x) initialState
    return (r, createGraphicsModule s') 

initialGraphicsModule = createGraphicsModule initialGraphicsState

runModule (Module m) x = m x

-- Program
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data ProgramState = ProgramState {
    graphicsModule :: GraphicsModule
}

renderInProgram :: (MonadState ProgramState m, MonadIO m) => Int -> m ()
renderInProgram x = do
    gm <- gets graphicsModule
    (r, gm') <- liftIO $ runModule gm x

    modify $ \g -> g { graphicsModule = gm' }

initialProgramState = ProgramState initialGraphicsModule

main = runStateT prog initialProgramState

prog = do
    renderInProgram 1
    renderInProgram 1
    renderInProgram 1
```

I can see how this could be quite easily extended to allow more functions in a module (instead of just `render`). I am not sure if I'm keeping the state correctly, though. That was the only way I saw to not expose the inner, stateful context (note that the outer monad to the module is just IO).

Also **I am aware of the fact that Lens could make it less verbose**. I deliberately chose to not depend on Lens, and I think it's really functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the `Module` approach is that you don't manage any state globally. Instead, each component (`Module`) manages its own state internally and you just express how they are connected together.

To give a simple example, let me first implement the standard type classes for `Module`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module Main where

import Prelude hiding ((.), id)
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Category
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Void

-- Module
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
newtype Module m a b =
    Module { runModule :: a -> m (b, Module m a b) }

instance (Monad m) => Category (Module m) where
    id = Module $ \x -> return (x, id)
    (Module g) . (Module f) = Module $ \x -> do
        (u, f') <- f x
        (v, g') <- g u
        return (v, g' . f')

mkGen :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> Module m a b
mkGen f = let m = Module $ \x -> do
                    y <- f x
                    return (y, m)
           in m

instance (Monad m) => Arrow (Module m) where
    arr f = mkGen (return . f)
    first (Module f) = Module $ \(x, y) -> do
        (r, m) <- f x
        return ((r, y), first m)

instance (Monad m) => Functor (Module m a) where
    fmap f (Module k) = Module $ \x -> do
        (y, k') <- k x
        return (f y, fmap f k')

instance (Monad m) => Applicative (Module m a) where
    pure x = let m = Module $ \_ -> return (x, m)
              in m
    (Module f) <*> (Module k) = Module $ \x -> do
        (h, f') <- f x
        (y, k') <- k x
        return (h y, f' <*> k')
```

The above functions allow creating modules and combining them together in various ways.

Now one of the main functions is to step a module with no input/output, producing its next state:

```
step :: (Monad m) => Module m () () -> m (Module m () ())
step (Module k) = liftM snd (k ())
```

For example, in your case you'd have a counter module, that keeps an internal state:

```
counter :: (Monad m) => Module m () Int
counter = let m i = Module $ \_ -> return (i, m (i + 1))
           in m 0
```

And a state-less module that just prints what it gets and has no output

```
render :: (MonadIO m, Show a) => Module m a ()
render = mkGen (liftIO . print)
```

Their combination is a module with no input or output, and stepping them prints the counter each time:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let m = counter >>> render
    step m >>= step >>= step
    return ()
```